# What is the difference between createEmbeddedView and createComponent?

Tags: angular

I am confused between use cases of `createEmbeddedView` and `createComponent`, i.e when to use which one.

Please come up with some cases that can tell about suitable setting to use either of them in "dynamic creation scenario".

Answer (score 70, accepted):

See [this workshop on DOM manipulation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vz9cNCkaPsY&t=2529s) or read [Working with DOM in Angular: unexpected consequences and optimization techniques](https://blog.angularindepth.com/working-with-dom-in-angular-unexpected-consequences-and-optimization-techniques-682ac09f6866) where I explain the difference with examples.

These both methods are used to dynamically add content to the component view (DOM). This content can be either a template or a component based. In Angular we usually manipulate the DOM using [ViewContainerRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef). And both these methods are available on it:

```
class ViewContainerRef {
    ...
    createEmbeddedView<C>(templateRef: TemplateRef<C>, context?: C, index?: number): EmbeddedViewRef<C>
    createComponent<C>(componentFactory: ComponentFactory<C>, index?: number, injector?: Injector, projectableNodes?: any[][], ngModule?: NgModuleRef<any>): ComponentRef<C>
}
```

To learn more about manipulating the DOM read [Exploring Angular DOM manipulation techniques using ViewContainerRef](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02).

#### createEmbeddedView

It's used to create a view using [TemplateRef](https://angular.io/api/core/TemplateRef). TemplateRef is created by Angular compiler when it encounters `ng-template` tag in your component html.
The view created using this method is called an `embedded view`.

```
import { VERSION, Component, ViewChild, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <ng-container #vc></ng-container>
      <ng-template #tpl>
          <h1>Hello, {{name}}</h1>
      </ng-template>
  `,
  styles: ['']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`;

  @ViewChild('tpl', {read: TemplateRef}) tpl: TemplateRef<any>;
  @ViewChild('vc', {read: ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.vc.createEmbeddedView(this.tpl);
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wtso1j)

This approach is used by all structural directives like `*ngIf` and `*ngFor` because they are all wrap a `ng-template`. For example, for `*ngIf` the code:

```
<div *ngIf="data">{{name}}</div>
```

is transformed into

```
<ng-template ngIf="data">
   <div>{{name}}</div>
```

And the `ngIf` directive uses `createEmbeddedView` internally:

```
@Directive({selector: '[ngIf]'})
export class NgIf {
    private _updateView() {
       ...
       if (this._thenTemplateRef) {
           this._thenViewRef =
               this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._thenTemplateRef, this._context);
```

#### createComponent

It's used to create a view using [ComponentFactory](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentFactory). It's created by Angular compiler when you specify a component in the `bootstrap` property of the module and so the compiler generates a factory for it. The view created using this method is called a `hostview`.

```
import { Component, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, NgZone, VERSION, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello Component!</h1>`,
  styles: [``]
})
export class HelloComponent  {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <ng-container #vc></ng-container>
  `,
  styles: ['']
})
export class AppComponent {

  @ViewChild('vc', {read:ViewContainerRef}) vc: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(HelloComponent);
    this.vc.createComponent(factory);
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m9mjg3).

To learn more about the difference between a host view and an embedded view read [What is the difference between a view, a host view and an embedded view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45027581/2545680)

Comment: Thanks @AngularInDepth.com for your reply. I followed your link to difference between "host view and embedded view" and now my understanding is that embedded views are suited to create dynamic **presentation** view. But, for a smart component, one that can do much more than displaying data, createComponent is the way to go. Am I right on this ?

Comment: @Blaze, you're welcome. Well, that's one way to look at it I suppose. Since embedded views are created from `ng-template` and don't have a class associated with them as opposed to components indeed there's not much logic can be put inside `embedded view`. However, I would say that mostly embedded views are used for reusable presentations. All structural directives make use of `ng-template`. I'll add that bit to the answer

Comment: One question, after ViewContainerRef#createComponent is called, can I ensure the component must be in DOM?

Comment: @Chao, it's in the DOM once the method returns.

Comment: I think angular in depth has changed home since this answer was last updated. 
@MaxKoretskyi Can you please update the URL to :
https://indepth.dev/posts/1134/working-with-dom-in-angular-unexpected-consequences-and-optimization-techniques