# Angular 6: how to have a component with non closing tags

Tags: angular, tags, components, angular6

Using Angular 6, I want to wrap certain pages (not all) with openCenteredPage and closeCenteredPage components (but with non closing tags), something like:

```
<openCenteredPage></openCenteredPage>
my HTML here
<closeCenteredPage></closeCenteredPage>
```

and for instance in openCenteredPage.component.html:

```
<div class="bounds page-wrapper">
  <div class="content" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxFlexFill >
    <div fxFlex="10" fxFlex.xs="55">
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="80">
        <div class="main-div">
            <section class="mat-typography">
```

But I have this error:

```
Unexpected closing tag "section". 
It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.
```

What is the best practice to have reusable piece of HTML with non-closing tags ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having unclosed component tags (which would always throw error), you can create

1. A single component like `myCustomComponent`.
2. Inject/add a dynamic component (`my-dynamic-component`, which has your html content)
   using `createComponent` method or `createEmbeddedView` method into your `myCustomComponent`

so
**`myCustomComponent.html`**

```
<div class="bounds page-wrapper">
  <div class="content" fxLayout="row" fxLayout.xs="column" fxFlexFill >
    <div fxFlex="10" fxFlex.xs="55">
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="80">
        <div class="main-div">
            <section class="mat-typography">
    <my-dynamic-component></my-dynamic-component>  <!-- inject your dynamic stuff here. -->
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46338790/what-is-the-difference-between-createembeddedview-and-createcomponent-in-angular) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. So if I understand correctly, you have to do it the other way around, by injecting a component to this generic component architecting my page with flex. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like that.

You must use only one tag to implement a behavior.

This would be something like this

```
<app-center>
  Your centered HTML content
</app-center>
```

HTML can't understand two different tags making a single one. So if HTML, the simplest markup language, can't do that, don't expect Angulat to do it.

(And if I didn't got it right, non-closing tags are the same as closing ones, so)

```
<app-center></app-center> === <app-center />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your thinking is not correct in angular way. You should always use closing tags, if you need pass custom content to component/route, then use

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

or

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

(ng-content can be named to use multiply in the component)